# convert object into date

Tags: java, object, casting, java.util.date

I get an `ArrayList` of `Object[]` from a database and I want to convert the `java.sql.Date` stored in an object into a `java.util.Date` (in order to use it in jfreechart):
my code is as follows:

fills up the Array of object with data from MySQL

```
 ArrayList<Object[]> mydata=new ArrayList<>(); 
 mydata=sqlGetter.getMdbObjectList(sqlString, null);


for(Object[] myobject : mydata){
        if (myobject[1].getClass()==java.sql.Date.class){
           java.util.Date mydate=null;
           mydate = Date ( myobject[1]);  
        } 
}
```

Netbeans return an error: "Java incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Date"

While I understand the idea, I would have expected to be able to cast the object into a Date after having checked that it is indeed of the right class.

I'm starting java, so please any helps on the obvious mistake that I must be doing would be useful.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for casting - search google. Also I'd suggest using instanceof instead of checking for a specific class (it could be a subtype, or a different type like timestamp, which still inherits from util.Date)

Comment: yes realised now that i had missed the parenthesis. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a cast. Additionally, you'd be better off using the `instanceof` operator:

```
for(Object[] myobject : mydata){
    // Note that java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date
    if (myobject[1] instanceof java.util.Date) {
        java.util.Date mydate = (java.util.Date) myobject[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I used your answer and the instance of.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to explicit cast the object to Date
ex: (Date) obj;